# Append the_contents outside of the loop

Tags: wordpress

When I call the following php file, I want the code to:

1. Get the latest blog post
2. Append it with some text
3. Save the appended blog post

The following code somewhat works in-so-far-as it will do steps 1 and 2 but will not save the contents as appended.  Any help is appreciated!  Thanks, novice wp developer.

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/blog/wp-load.php' );
$wp_did_header = true;

$args = array( 'numberposts' => 1 );
$recent_posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach($recent_posts as $post)
{
    $post->post_content .= '<br />Some text appended to Post';
    $post->post_content = add_filter('the_content', $post->post_content);
    return $post->post_content;
}
?>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please be specific to your problem.

Comment: Do you want to CHANGE the post content in the DB while looping ??

Comment: Yes, I want to CHANGE the post content in the DB.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use filters, just display text after the post

```
  foreach ($recent_posts as $post) :
  setup_postdata($post);
  the_content();
  echo '<br />Some text appended to Post';
  endforeach;
```

Comment: not sure, if not save in DB then where? This is a question to Brendan, where you want to save your post?

Comment: Rahil, the Post is already saved in the DB.  I am just trying to update it with some additional text.  So, Update would probably be more correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[add_filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) accepts second parameter as callback function name not just string.

`return` cannot be call inside loops like you did. It will just stop executing script.

`return` only be declared inside functions/methods

Your loop will be like this:

```
foreach($recent_posts as $post)
{
    echo $post->post_content . '<br />Some text appended to Post';
}
```

Actually you don't have to apply any filter here. Just append the `$post` property `post_content` with your value.

Comment: This is just a different guess. Dynamic change of content may be what Brendan needed, but have nothing to do with "save" clearly described on point 3. I'll not down vote, will just wait for his explanation.

Comment: @MichalS What OP needs you can see clearly in the code. The word _save_ means to append the loop posts content with custom content. Using the filter `the_content` he applied.

Comment: your opinion. If someone honestly describes himself as a "novice" I'll rather trust a description then a code. From code point of view - you are right. But once more, with so unclear question, down voting is not fair. I'll gladly change my answer if is really wrong.

Comment: thanks for remove. BTW, foreach in loop of 1 post also is not needed, and for display content of post is recommended to use the_content().

Comment: Michal S, you are correct.  I want to Update the post with the appended text.  "Save" may not have been the correct description.  Thx

Comment: The example provided above does indeed append the post with the "some text appended to Post" but when I return to the blog, it has not updated the post in the database. There must be some other "commit" mechanism I'm not invoking?

Comment: Brendan you are still unclear: should it stay for ever in DB or just appear in browser?

Comment: It should "stay forever", or persist in the DB.  You may also be correct in that the Loop is unnecessary for 1 record, however, I don't know another way to be sure to get the very last post.