# How to append a wordpress post outside the loop?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to update blog posts outside of the Loop. When the following php code is called, the code shall:

1. Get the latest (most recent) blog post
2. Append it with some text (example below has hard-coded text, but may be a variable)
3. Update the appended blog post

The following code somewhat works in-so-far-as it will do steps 1 and 2 but will not update the actual contents of the blog post that persists in the DB. Any help is appreciated!

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/blog/wp-load.php' );
$wp_did_header = true;

$args = array( 'numberposts' => 1 );
$recent_posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach($recent_posts as $post)
{
    $post->post_content .= '<br />Some text appended to Post';
    $post->post_content = add_filter('the_content', $post->post_content);
}
return $post->post_content;
?>
```

Comment: Why you are asking the same question again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append the\_contents outside of the loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181702/append-the-contents-outside-of-the-loop)

Comment: I was unable to answer anymore questions.  The system said it would auto move to chat, but apparently I don't have enough "points" to chat.  You guys almost had the answer but not yet.  I've answered your followup questions regarding persistence.  It is strait forward.  Update an existing post outside the loop with some text.